# Rooting android emulator - Error?

Tags: android-emulator

I have to root android emulator. I've found some articles, but I've got the same error every time! It's 'cannot create su: not enough memory'!
What I did:

```
1. adb push su /data/local
2. adb shell 
3. #su
4. #mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
5. # cd /system/xbin
6. # mv su osu
7. # cat /data/local/su > su // I've got an error!!! 
//Cannot create su: Out of memory!
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got answer on my question! 
I must run an android emulator with -partition-size 128 option.
It should look like below:

```
android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator -avd MyAndroidVirtualDeviceName -partition-size 128
```

After that I can root my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like /system/xbin is not rw.
The fact that mount -o remount,rw does not return errors doesn't mean that it succeeded.
Check what mount reports for /system after the remount.
Also, see if you have proper permissions to write there.

Comment: How can I rename su to osu if I don't have permission?

Comment: mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system - It writes me 'permission denied' again (((

Comment: I don't know the answer to "how can I get root access in the emulator". I'm just saying that I've seen RO filesystems get "remount,rw"ed without errors but then yaffs2 is not such a system. Still something similar used to work when you try to mount a CD image as rw, and a flash memory with a hardware rw lock. They both were reporting that they are out of space. Operations like renaming ONLY SEEMed to work. But that was couple of years ago - no idea what is the actual problem with the emulator. Sorry.